# jQuery resize blinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that when the width of `.tabla_gs_gm` exceeds `.content`, `.tabla_gs_gm` disappears and another div appears. This already works but when resized screen blinks between the two divs. I'm sure it's for the resize function but what could I do?

**jQuery:**

```
<script>    
    function jqUpdateSize(){

        var content = $(".content").width();                                        
        var tabla_gs_gm = $(".tabla_gs_gm").width();

        if(tabla_gs_gm >= content){
            $(".grillas_mobile").css("display","block");
            $(".grillas_desktop").css("display","none");
        }else{
            $(".grillas_desktop").css("display","block");
            $(".grillas_mobile").css("display","none");
        } 

    };
    $(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);
    $(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="content">
        <div class="grillas_desktop">
            <table>
                //content
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="grillas_mobile">
            <table>
                //content
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grillas_desktop, .grillas_mobile{
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

table.tabla_gs_gm{
    margin: auto;
    width: 99%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tabla_gs_gm td{
    padding: 3px;
}

.tabla_gs_gm .class_label{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.grillas_mobile select{
    margin: 3px 0px 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 3px;
}
```

Comment: First thing you can do: Set up an example we can work with ;-)

Comment: I've updated the question with the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set height of ".tabla_gs_gm" to 0px when this exceeds content and now doesn't blink.

```
<script>    
    function jqUpdateSize(){

        var content = $(".content").width();                                        
        var tabla_gs_gm = $(".tabla_gs_gm").width();

        if(tabla_gs_gm >= content){
            $(".grillas_mobile").css("display","block");
            $(".grillas_desktop").css("height","0px");
        }else{
            $(".grillas_desktop").css("height","auto");
            $(".grillas_mobile").css("display","none");
        } 

    };
    $(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);
    $(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a short period, neither object has class `resizing`, so you're seeing some interesting results. You can pick any common parent for this, but I will use `body`. You can add a class to `body` that indicates what is currently resizing and what is not, and that way your corresponding CSS selectors will be applied at the same time:

```
<script>    
    function jqUpdateSize(){

        var content = $(".content").width();
        var tabla_gs_gm = $(".tabla_gs_gm").width();

        if(tabla_gs_gm > content){
            $('body').addClass('mobileResizing');
        }else{
            $('body').removeClass('mobileResizing');
        }   


    };
    $(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);
    $(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);
</script>
```

You can then set your CSS up to react to these events like so:

for when `tabla_gs_gm > content` is true, prefix your selectors with `body.mobileResizing`:

```
body.mobileResizing .grillas_mobile {
  /* CSS for mobile when its resizing */
}
body.mobileResizing .grillas_desktop {
  /* CSS for desktop when mobile is resizing */
}
```

and for when `tabla_gs_gm > content` is is false use `body:not(.mobileResizing)`:

```
body:not(.mobileResizing) .grillas_mobile {
  /* CSS for mobile when desktop is resizing */
}
body:not(.mobileResizing) .grillas_desktop {
  /* CSS for desktop when its resizing */
}
```

and you can insert `display: none;` to hide or `display: block;` to show whichever elements you want given the above conditions.

Comment: I've tried with your code and still blinks. I've updated the question with your code and some of the html and css.

Comment: Now it's working, I've set height of ".tabla_gs_gm" to 0px when this exceeds content. Thanks anyway!